# Regress rotation + translation between 3D coordinate frames

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

I have a large set of 3D points X in one coordinate frame, and another set of noisy obervations of the same points Y in a different coordinate system. These points are homogeneous representations so each one has 4 components.

I would like to regress a 4x4 matrix M which optimally maps one coordinate system to the other: Y = MX. This matrix should have six independent parameters associated with rotations and translations.

Any suggestion how to approach the regression of M in Python ? Does opencv for instance offer a method to do a 3D perspective transform ?

Comment: Use the [Kabsch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks Nico. There is a very nice python implementation [here](https://github.com/charnley/rmsd) which worked perfectly for my task. I also found the [original paper](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?S0567739476001873) very concise and readable